# Circular Importing of ViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, circular-dependency

In Appdelegate I am Importing Some Class for showing the view and in that view I have required to import the Same AppDelegate for accessing some method and variable but when I am doing this. Its shows circular import error.

I have tried by importing by `@class` in .h file and import in .m file.

Answer (score 3):

In both classes you should only use `@class` in the .h file and then add the `#import` in the .m file. This is the correct solution for the problem you describe.

Note that the circularity could be bigger because a 3rd class could be `#import`ed and it in turn `#import`s another class to make the circular link. Generally you should use `@class` in your .h files unless you have to `#import` (for the superclass and `@protocol`s you implement).

Comment: I have tried by the @class in . h file but when I import in .m file it start showing errors...

Comment: So you need to look at what other files are being imported in your .h files (including in the files imported from your .m files). Generally, just go through your files moving the imports to the .m files.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using only one import in this class... Is this relater to compiler in any way. I am using LLVM GCC 4.2 Compiler in this project...

Comment: No, it isn't compiler specific. If you still have issues then please show the code.

Comment: Thanks wain, I just use .mm in place of .m file...and problem get solved...but still didn't get why this happend...